# Failed to perform comma seperated list aggregation in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have an entity as under

```
public class A
    {
        public string TestMethodName { get; set; }
        public string FailedFor { get; set; }
    }
```

I am populating as under and then performing a union

```
            List<A> aCollection = new List<A>();
            List<A> bCollection = new List<A>();

            aCollection.Add(new A { TestMethodName = "Method1", FailedFor = "DPLServerURL" });
            aCollection.Add(new A { TestMethodName = "Method2", FailedFor = "DPLServerURL" });
            aCollection.Add(new A { TestMethodName = "Method3", FailedFor = "DPLServerURL" });
            aCollection.Add(new A { TestMethodName = "Method4", FailedFor = "DPLServerURL" });


            bCollection.Add(new A { TestMethodName = "Method1", FailedFor = "OrderXmlLocation" });
            bCollection.Add(new A { TestMethodName = "Method2", FailedFor = "OrderXmlLocation" });
            bCollection.Add(new A { TestMethodName = "Method5", FailedFor = "OrderXmlLocation" });

            var kk = aCollection.Union(bCollection);
```

What I am looking for is that a group by on the TestMethodNames and the FailedFor should be comma seperated.

e.g. The final output should be

```
Method1  DPLServerUrl,OrderXmlLocation
Method2   DPLServerUrl,OrderXmlLocation
Method3   DPLServerUrl
Method4   DPLServerUrl
Method5   OrderXmlLocation
```

My attempt

```
 var mm  = kk.GroupBy(g => g.TestMethodName)
                  .Select(group =>
                        new
                        {
                            Name = group.Key,
                            AggregateFailedFor= group.Aggregate("",(a, b) => a.Join(",",b.FailedFor))
                        });
```

I am getting compile time error

**Member 'string.Join(string, params string[])' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead**

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is self explanatory. `Join` is static.. so therefore you cannot call it on an instance variable. You must call it via the type name (e.g, `string`):

```
Students = group.Aggregate("", (a, b) => string.Join(",", a, b.FailedFor))
//                                       ^^^^^^ this
```

Note that the aggregate will no doubt put a comma at the beginning of your results, because the first call will be "join nothing and FailedFor using a comma", which results in ",FailedFor".

EDIT:

Just changed your code to this:

```
kk.GroupBy(g => g.TestMethodName)
    Select(group =>
        new
        {
            Name = group.Key,
            Students = group.Aggregate("", (a, b) => 
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a))
                {
                    return b.FailedFor;
                }
                else 
                {
                    return string.Join(",", a, b.FailedFor);
                }
            })
        });
```

..and this is the result (which you said you were after):

[image: Query results]

Comment: How to overcome that beginning comma. I can do the same thing using String builder e.g.group.Aggregate(new Stringbulder(), (a, b) => a.Append("," + b.FailedFor).tostring()). But in both the cases the extra comma is coming for which I need to do some extra coding for stripping it out.Is it not possible to handle it using string.join..in some way?